# How many times the Saraswati Beeja mantra needs to be repeated?

Tags: mantras, saraswati, numbers

Assume that a guru gave upadesa of Saraswati mantra to a person.

ऐं । is the Beeja mantra for Saraswati Devi.

Does the exact number of times the Beeja mantra should be repeated is mentioned in scriptures?

Or has to be done based on the number told by the guru?

Or it solely depends on the sadhana I.e., until the sadhaka experience mantra siddi?

Comment: For purascharan u mean? Usually for ekakshara mantras (like hrim, klim etc.) one lakh is the prescribed number.

Comment: @Rickross Yeah...

Comment: Noticed that someone has downvoted both your question as well as my answer. But failing to understand why

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, don't know.

Comment: It's being done by [this user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/713/mozibur-ullah). He does not any reasons for downvoting but still randomly downvotes posts that are in front of his eyes. He has downvoted 4 posts by me without any reasons and so I asked him --  What's your problem? Why are you doing this? -- But there was no reply. Let's see what he does in the future. we can complain if it becomes repetitive.

Comment: @Rickross How do you know who downvoted? From any comments? I'm also getting some downvotes that are not deserved. Another user is also facing the same...

Comment: I was not aware that you are also a victim. But I have noticed that its him who is doing the blind downvoting. I m 100% sure that he is doing it on my posts. If he has done the same on other posts too then I'm not so sure. You have to monitor closely to know :D .. His behavior is like that of a person who comes in with a gun and starts firing at random targets.

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, recently I flagged regarding this....

Comment: Okay but IMO if it keeps occurring then a better way is to complain using the "contact us" form. Mods here can't see who voted on a post but CMs and the staffs can.

Comment: See today only he downvoted [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/41166/4732) of course without any reasons. And he probably upvoted the other two answers. So, he has 3 votes for today (till now). His rep was 155 now its 154 (one downvote gives you -1) https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/713/mozibur-ullah I am not sure what's his problem

Comment: @Rickross Ha, maybe he thinks to decrease your reputation as you are one of the most reputed people in our community... :-|

Comment: Haha that is not a sensible reason :D .. He can not do that alone... also if this continues then he will soon run short of Rep to downvote. I think you need 125 or something to be able to downvote. And with each downvote he is loosing 1 point.

Answer (score 4):

The number of times a Mantra is required to be chanted during Purascharana depends on the number of letters the Mantra is formed of. It is usually N lakh where N denotes the number of letters the Mantra has.

For example, the Gayatri Mantra is 24-syllabled. So, 24 lakh is the prescribed number for it's Purascharana.

So, for mono-syllabled Mantras (like aim, klim etc.) it is one lakh.

> The Gâyatrî is to be repeated also. The food offered by a thief,
> Chândâla, Ksattriya or Vais’ya is very inferior. The food of a S’ûdra,
> or the companion with a S’ûdra or taking food in the same line with a
> S’ûdra leads one to suffer in the terrible hells as long as there are
> the Sun and Moon. **The Puras’charanam of Gâyatrî is repeating this
> twenty four lakh times (i.e., as many lakh times as there are
> syllables in the Gâyatrî)**
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 11.21**

In general, irrespective of how many letters the Mantra is made of, at least one lakh Japa is required for attaining Mantra Siddhi.

This is mentioned by [Swami Sivananda](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=525):

> Get the Mantra initiation from your Guru. Or pray to your Ishta Devata
> and start doing Japa of the particular Mantra, if you find it
> difficult to get a Guru.
>
> - **METHOD OF MANTRA PURASCHARANA**
>
> The repetition of a Mantra with rigid spiritual observances a fixed
> number of times to obtain quick spiritual progress is known as Mantra
> Purascharana. It can be performed for material progress too. The
> practitioner should observe certain rules and undergo strict dietetic
> discipline to ensure quick Mantra Siddhi.
>
> During the Purascharana take only fresh vegetables, fruits, milk,
> roots, barley and Havis-Anna (rice cooked with ghee, sugar, milk). A
> Sadhaka can live on pure Bhiksha (alms) also. If you can live on milk
> alone during the period of Purascharana it is highly laudable. You can
> have Mantra Siddhi even by repeating the Mantra a lakh of times.
>
> Select any holy place of pilgrimage on the banks of sacred Ganga,
> confluence of rivers, mountain valleys of charming scenery, temples,
> Tulasi gardens, below Asvattha trees or convert a portion of your
> house into a temple by keeping the picture of the Lord, burning
> incense etc., and by suitable decorations. Purascharana done in holy
> places has a benefit hundred times superior to that done in one's own
> house.
>
> **You can select any Mantra for Purascharana. Your Guru Mantra or Ishta Mantra is the best. Sandhya time, sunrise, sunset, midday are
> all recommended for Japa. Repeat the Mantra as many lakhs of times as
> there are letters in the Mantra. You can do half of that number. In no
> case the number should be less than a lakh.**
>
> Sit facing East or North during Japa. Select Siddha, Padma, Svastika
> or Virasana for Japa. Never sit for Japa with a loaded stomach. Have
> fixed timings for Japa. Take a bath before you start, if possible, or
> at least wash hands and feet. Perform Achamana or sipping of
> Sanctified Mantra water. Deer skin, cloth, blanket, Kusa grass or
> tiger skin can be used as seats while doing Japa. Spatika, Tulasi,
> Rudraksha Malas can be used for counting the number of Japa. Have a
> Mala with 108 beads or half or one-fourth that number.