# Will chanting the same mantra 10 lakh times earn Siddhi power?

Tags: mantras, siddhi

I was told that if you chant a mantra 100 000 times you get the siddhi that correspondes to this specific mantra. is this true?or do i need to chant more? There's one siddhi I need to obtain and im studing the proper way to do it.
I need the siddhi of yogic materialization,for the good of my country.

Comment: If it is for Siddhi purpose, mantra should be received as initiation and then Guru can guide how much to chant and things like that (or you may receive instructions with other mediums, like in your dreams)...

Comment: See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40963/4732). For mantra siddhi first diksha, then purascharan is to be done. How many times a particular mantra is to be chanted during purascharan depends on the mantra itself. But usually 1 lakh is the prescribed number not 10.

Comment: This looks like a personal-advice question which is off-topic here.